# Magento 2: Remove requirejs in checkout phase

Tags: magento2, requirejs, checkout-page

I have a question over Magento 2 checkout phase.
I don't want to talk about the decision of force developer to user requirejs knockoutjs and so on...

Exist an extension which reproduce the checkout phase without the dependency of requirejs?